# GitHub actions splitting workflow file

Tags: github-actions

Is it possible to split a GitHub Actions workflow file and reference it from other? I need to deploy an application into multiple environments i.e. staging and production and would like to share half of the steps to minimize maintenance.

Comment: In your case, maybe you should consider create actions:

https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/building-actions

Answer (score 7):

You can split each action in the following file format:

folder named "test-action"

.github/test-action/action.yml

with contents

```
  name: test-action
  description: test action
  inputs:
    test_input:
      description: key
      required: true
  runs:
    using: composite
    steps:
      - name: echo test
        shell: bash
        run: |
          echo ${{inputs.test_input}}
```

then you can refer to the action from any yml:

```
  - name: test-action
    uses: ./.github/test-action
    with:
      test_input: "test-string-value"
```

the key here was to make sure that the file within your named action folder would be called "action.yml"

Answer (score 1):

It seems like there is no way as CircleCI allows defining commands that are a set of steps: https://github.community/t5/GitHub-Actions/reusing-sharing-inheriting-steps-between-jobs-declarations/td-p/37849

At this moment, I guess we can use `repository_dispatch` as a workaround.
In this example, it handles events between repositories, but I think we can apply this in same repository: https://blog.marcnuri.com/triggering-github-actions-across-different-repositories/